# UI5: Add Tree to IconTabFilter Content

Tags: sapui5

I have an icon tab filter that upon the user selecting it, I would like to show a tree.

The logic of how I handle the user selection of the icon is provided here

[Handle IconTab Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586709/sapui5-icontabbar-icontabfilter-trigger-icon-tab-select)

The problem I have is the JS which will create the tree node is not working. The logic to do this is below: -

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
                        "idocs1" : [ {
                                "Docnum" : "00063463",
                                "Mestyp" : "MATMAS",
                                "Status" : "53",
                                "Sndprn" : "EXTSYS1",
                                "Direct" : "Inbound",
                                "Message" : "Material 00002342 Created",
                                "messages" : [ {
                                    "message" : "Material 00002342 Created"
                                } ],
                                "segments" : [ {
                                    "segment" : "E1MARAM",
                                    "fields" : [ {
                                        "fieldName" : "MATNR"
                                    } ]

                                } ]
                            } ]
                        });

                        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);

                        var tgtPath = "/idocs1/0/segments";
                        var oTree = new sap.ui.commons.Tree("tree");

                        oTree.bindAggregation("nodes", tgtPath, function(
                                sId, oContext) {

                            var treePath = oContext.getPath();

                            var bindTextName = '';
                            if (treePath.indexOf("fields") !== -1) {
                                bindTextName = "fieldName";
                            } else {
                                bindTextName = "segment";
                            }

                            alert("here = " + oContext + " ---- "
                                    + bindTextName);
                            return new sap.ui.commons.TreeNode()
                                    .bindProperty("text", bindTextName);

                        });


                        var myButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button("btn");

                        myButton.setText("Hello World!");

                        myButton
                                .placeAt("idViewRoot--idViewDetail--toolBar-content");

                        oTree
                                .placeAt("idViewRoot--idViewDetail--toolBar-content");
```

This logic is in a method, which is invoked when the user selects a specific IconTab.

I have the button in place to ensure it will add something to the IconTab content (when the tree logic is commented out).

I have noticed that if I was to try and create two buttons of the same ID, then the above code (i.e the method) is invoked twice.

If I enable the tree logic, the method is being called twice, thus I am getting errors for a duplicate tree node.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Martin

Comment: Have fixed it now. The issue was if you put an alert in the factory function "bindAggregation" it appears to error with a dup tree ID.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you would like to add the content later? You can also add a specific content for each IconTab which is shown when the user clicks on it.
This should also solve your problem.

If this is not convenient for your case, I think you should set the content either on the IconTabBar or the IconTabFilter after clicking on the IconTab and not putting it by yourself in the content.